# xsl fo center a table and an image using display-align="center"

Tags: image, centering, xsl-fo, apache-fop, xmltable

I'm learning xsl:fo and training using the xml example file on w3schools : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml, which I modified a bit to add a "PICTURE" tag.

I parse the file to gather the information of each CD in a table, using `xsl:for-each`, `fo:table` and `fo:external-graphic`. I use `display-align="center"` for both of them, as suggested in previous questions, and it does not work : images and tables stay aligned on the left.

Here is a code sample (I removed most of the style attributes to make it more readable) :

```
<xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD">              

            <fo:block text-align="center">
                <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/> - <xsl:value-of select="ARTIST"/>
            </fo:block>

            <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic content-height="scale-to-fit" width="2.00in" content-width="2.00in" display-align="center">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">pictures/<xsl:value-of select="PICTURE"/>.jpg</xsl:attribute>
                </fo:external-graphic>
            </fo:block>

            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" font-family="Helvetica" text-indent="2em" space-before="2em" display-align="center">
                <fo:table-column column-width="4cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="4cm"/>                   
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Country :</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell><fo:block><xsl:value-of select="COUNTRY"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Company :</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell><fo:block><xsl:value-of select="COMPANY"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Price :</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell><fo:block><xsl:value-of select="PRICE"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Year :</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell><fo:block><xsl:value-of select="YEAR"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>

        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Did you try text-align="center" ? You are aligning left/right.It will work for the image but not the table, you need more work for that.

Comment: I did try text-align on the image then, and it worked, yes :)

Answer (score 3):

`display-align="center"` is for centering vertically (i.e., in the block-progression-direction).  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#display-align.  (Also, `display-align` doesn't apply to `fo:table`.  If you did want to center the table vertically, you'd have to use `display-align="center"` on the FO that *contains* the `fo:table`.)

For left-right centering (in the inline-progression-direction), use `text-align="center"`: see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#text-align

However, `text-align` doesn't apply to `fo:table`, so you need to put it on an `fo:table-and-caption` and put the `fo:table` as a child of the `fo:table-and-caption` (and the `fo:table-caption` is optional).  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_table-and-caption

Comment: text-align works perfectly for my image, thanks ! However my table is not displayed on the pdf (tehre is nothing) when I put it into <fo:table-and-caption> tags (I have tried without any style, there is no text-align at all for now)

Comment: I use fop. my xsl:fo tags are within an xsl document (command line : fop -xml cd_catalog.xml -xsl cd_catalogfo.xsl -pdf cd_catalog.pdf)

Comment: I realize I have indeed a warning : "The following feature isn't implemented by Apache FOP, yet: fo:table-and-caption"

Comment: Then put the `fo:table` in an `fo:block` instead.